# Is it possible to add custom application data to an email via the Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am currently sending email via the Gmail API using the [Google Node SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client). I am successful in doing so, but my application requires that I be able to attach specific identifiers to emails that I send in order to be able to track and process certain events correctly.

I have heard of custom metadata being added to emails sent through other services such as Mailchimp, Postmark, etc so it seems like some sort of standard to be able to do this in email. I however, have not been able to find how to do this via the Gmail API specifically. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

No, you cannot add custom application data to messages sent via Gmail API.

#### Reference:

The corresponding [Message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages) resource doesn't include any property for custom metadata.

And the related methods [send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) and [insert](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/insert) don't allow this either.

#### Issue Tracker:

A related feature request was reported in Issue Tracker, I'd suggest you to [star it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue):

- [Add Custom Metadata to Email Messages via Gmail Api](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68785657)

#### Workaround:

I'd suggest you to use [labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels) to identify messages.